# Create angularjs toaster popup windows with buttons

Tags: angularjs, hottowel

I use johns papa toaster popup windows in my angularjs project.

```
  toaster.pop("warning", "Inspections not found!");
```

At some point I need to create popup window with button to trigger some function.Is it possible to implement?

Comment: 2k rep and you are asking a question like "is it possible to implement"?

Answer (score 0):

You can have a custom service implemented and then use [UI bootstrap](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) modal window to show custom dialogs with buttons and text you want.